# Performance differences between using ":not" and ".not()" selectors?

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors, css-selectors

Are there any speed/efficiency differences between the following two lines.

```
$("table td:not(:first-child)")
```

and

```
$("table td").not(":first-child")
```

I would think that the first would be better since it is removes objects, but is there an actual difference and is it substantial.

Thanks

Comment: http://jsperf.com/jquery-css3-not-vs-not

Comment: That may be more my question I am not really sure how to accurately measure it. I would assume a smaller page would have no issue but at what point does it make a differnce?

Comment: There is an immediately visible difference in *readability*. Do other types of difference concern you in your application?

Comment: I agree I really like the readability, but I want to make sure I am not losing significant performance for readability.

Comment: I find the second one easier to read, so I'd start out that way and revisit it if I noticed a performance problem on a particular page.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

As you can see from the [jsperf](http://jsperf.com/jquery-css3-not-vs-not) test, `:not` is on average about twice as fast.  Overall though this performance will likely be a very small part of your overall execution time.

The jquery docs state:

> The .not() method will end up providing you with more readable
> selections than pushing complex selectors or variables into a :not()
> selector filter. In most cases, it is a better choice.

So really it's up to you to decide if the fractions of a second you gain outweigh the readability.

Comment: Also, readability is somewhat personal too. I don't really have a problem with the readability of :not. Especially compared to other things I see coders do that are far less readable.

Comment: I get an "Internal Server Error" at the jsperf link above. Maybe a [different revision](https://jsperf.com/jquery-css3-not-vs-not/32)?

Answer (score 15):

Depends on the browser.

Browsers that support `querySelectorAll` will get a performance boost with...

```
$("table td:not(:first-child)")
```

...because it is a valid selector. Older browsers *(IE7 and lower)* will not.

You need to be careful with the `:not()` selector though. jQuery (Sizzle) extends it with non-standard selectors, so it's easy to break `qSA`.