# not deleted css class elements

Tags: jquery

How do I get elements that are not deleted class ".deleted"?

```
<ul class="users">
    <li class="user">mack</li>
    <li class="user">david</li>
    <li class="user">Resa</li>
    <li class="user deleted">Stock</li>
    <li class="user">fame</li>
    <li class="user">clock</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

so; you can do it with css selector and method.

**.not()**

```
jQuery("ul.users li").not(".deleted");
```

or **jQuery(":not()")**

```
jQuery("ul.users li:not(.deleted)");
```

is between using “:not” and “.not()” selectors

See [Performance differences between using ":not" and ".not()" selectors?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8845811/performance-differences-between-using-not-and-not-selectors)

Answer (score 5):

Use [`:not()`](http://api.jquery.com/not-selector/):

```
$("li:not(.deleted)")
```

Answer (score 4):

```
$('.users .user').not('.deleted');
```

Answer (score 4):

```
$("ul.users > li.user:not(.deleted)");
```

Answer (score 3):

With jQuery:

```
$(".users li:not(.deleted)")
```