# jQuery remove() everything except an item

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors, equals

I currently have the following code:

```
$( '.spandiv:eq(1)' ).remove();
```

This very nicely removes the second (as it uses 0-based indexing) item in the span list, which is great.  However, I have a question.

Is it possible to remove everything **except** the second item?

I know I could code up using the `lt()` and `gt()' but wondered if there was a`not equal` option?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [:not](http://api.jquery.com/not-selector/) or [.not()](http://api.jquery.com/not/)

```
$( '.spandiv:not(:eq(1))' ).remove();
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/j4T9J/)

Comment: Ahh, nice - didn't realise you could do that!  What's the performance hit, any idea?

Comment: @Homer_J I would recommend using `$('.spandiv').not(':eq(1)')` over `$('.spandiv:not(:eq(1))')` , because the `.spandiv:not(:eq(1))` will - I think that it is still true - force jQuery to use [Swizzle](http://sizzlejs.com/) for the whole query, while `$('.spandiv').not(':eq(1)')` will find the elements by the class `spandiv` using the native functionality (for modern browsers)  and then just filter that result.

Comment: The performance hit won't be that noticeable unless you have a lot of elements to filter, and wether you use `:not` or `.not` doesn't really matter that much, as Sizzle is jQuery's selector engine, and it will be used anyway.

Comment: Thanks, in one section there are over 400 elements!  So be interesting to see how it works.

Comment: @Homer_J, @adeneo jQuery/Swizzle first checks if it is a simple selector and uses `getElementsByTagName`, `getElementByID` or `getElementsByClassName` for them (if `getElementsByClassName` is not supported Swizzle will travers the _whole_ DOM). If the selector is not a simple one Swizzle will try to use `querySelectorAll` if it is not possible (in that case because of the `:eq`) it will start the _fallback_ to traverse the _whole_ DOM. So if `document.querySelectorAll(yourQuery)` does not work, and you have a noticeable performance impact with `$(yourQuery)` you may want to split it up.

Comment: Thanks for that, appreciated.  Am using the `.not()` version as there appears to be an increase in performance.  Not fully tested but it does appear to be faster.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8845811/performance-differences-between-using-not-and-not-selectors

Comment: @adeneo  for completeness I added a test that removes the element from the resultset without using `not` and `eq`, [jsperf.com/not-not-test/2](http://jsperf.com/not-not-test/2), for many cases it for sure not relevant, but it is always good to have in mind.

Comment: @t.niese - for completeness I added a native solution, that should be a lot faster than jQuery, not that it's very relevant either -> http://jsperf.com/not-not-test/3

Comment: @adeneo But there you need to take care that jQuery did not add anything to the elements and/or their descendants (data or event listeners), because this removes the data cleanup step of jQuery, for sure a valid way if the context in which it is used is perfectly known.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [**.not()**](http://api.jquery.com/not/)

```
$('.spandiv').not(':eq(1)').remove();
```

[JSFIDDLE DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/9u4kb/)