# JQuery .on() complex selector with multiple includes and excludes

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a form that I want to auto save based on the inputs changing value, but am having problems with my selector. My problem seems to be specifically with the inputs I am trying to exclude as the function still fires when those inputs change.

```
$('#OrderDetailsTabs').on('change',
    'form[id^="frmWorkOrderHdr"] input[type=text],form[id^="frmWorkOrderHdr"] input[type=number], form[id^="frmWorkOrderHdr"] select, form[id^="frmWorkOrderHdr"] textarea, input:not("#WOHdr_FinishedGoodsItemId_AutoComplete, .itemSelectorCategory1, .itemSelectorCategory2")',
    function () {
    saveWOHdr(event, this);
})
```

So for example, when input `#WOHdr_FinishedGoodsItemId_AutoComplete` changes, the `saveWOHdr` event is still firing and the `this` object is indeed the `#WOHdr_FinishedGoodsItemId_AutoComplete` input.

The selector I have so far is what I came up with after reading [this other SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7144976/jquery-multiple-not-selector?lq=1).

I think the inclusionary selector string I have could also be cleaned up to reduce the repetitive `form[id^="frmWorkOrderHdr"]`parent qualifier...but I didn't want to get too fancy until I got it at least performing the way I want.

Answer (score 0):

Give them a common class.

```
<input class="save-auto some-other-style-class">
```

Makes the selector *sooooo* simple

```
$('#OrderDetailsTabs').on('change','.save-auto', saveWOHdr);
```

Much easier to read and much simpler to see those elements for troubleshooting