# multiple :not jquery / ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I currently have:

```
$(document).on('click','#audits-lines-grid table tbody tr td:not(td:nth-child(9n))',function(){(...)
```

I need to add a :not(first-child) as well.

I've tried several syntaxes, including

```
$(document).on('click','#audits-lines-grid table tbody tr td:not(td:nth-child(9n)):not(first-child)',function(){
```

but it doesn't work, any idea how to get this right?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [jQuery - multiple :not selector](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7144976/jquery-multiple-not-selector)

Comment: This is `:not(:first-child)`

Comment: And if you don't want the first child, nor the 9th and there is no more than 16 children by row, you could use `td:not(:nth-child(8n + 1))`

Comment: tried  $(document).on('click','#audits-lines-grid table tbody tr td:not(td:nth-child(9n)), :not(:first-child)' it doesn't work ... $(document).on('click','#audits-lines-grid table tbody tr td:not(td:nth-child(9n)), #audits-lines-grid table tbody tr td:not(:first-child)' doesnt work either

Comment: td:not(:nth-child(8n + 1)), that one work, thanks

Answer (score 1):

The `:not` selector can take multiple CSS selectors as arguments (
http://api.jquery.com/not-selector ). 
E.g.

```
$('div:not(.a,.b)').empty()
```

So, in your case would be:

```
td:not(:nth-child(9n), :first-child)
```

Final:

```
$(document).on('click','#audits-lines-grid table tbody tr td:not(:nth-child(9n), :first-child)',function(){(...)
```

Here is the demo jsfiddle as well: http://jsfiddle.net/HFfcP/

Comment: This is `:fisrt-child` not just `first-child`