# Select all inputs, except elements inside Summernote's div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, summernote

[Summernote](https://summernote.org/)'s modals have modals with inputs inside.

[image]

My JS goes here:

```
$('input, select, textarea').on('change',
    function(e){
        var inputs = $('input:text, input[type="radio"]:checked').map(
            function(){
                /* show values */
            }
        ).get();
    }
);
```

Tried to use [not()](http://api.jquery.com/not/) but it doesn't work:

```
var inputs = $('input:text, input[type="radio"]:checked')
    .not('div.note-editor > input')
    .map()
    .get();
```

Comment: Your ".not" might work if you use, ".not('div.form-group > input')" instead

Comment: I can't use it, because needed inputs inside form-group too :(

Comment: Well you can also do ".not('div.note-editor div.form-group > input.note-link-text')" you can be as specific as you need

Comment: Yeah, I might do that, however what if summernote have inputs that aren't wrapped in .form-group? I don't really know how many of them it has.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using `not` is correct, but you should remove the `>` as it specifies a direct child, which the `input` is not. So

```
var inputs = $('input:text, input[type="radio"]:checked')
    .not('div.note-editor input')
    .map()
    .get();
```

Comment: Ninja! Thought that `>` specifies _indirect_ child. My bad :(

Comment: BTW as [Adrien Be](https://stackoverflow.com/users/759452/adrien-be) wrote [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29006774/5193609) `:not` has better performance than `.not()`, see [Performance differences between using “:not” and “.not()” selectors?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8845811/performance-differences-between-using-not-and-not-selectors)